# Pass a variable into chrome.extension.connect

Tags: javascript, variables, google-chrome-extension, scope

I'm trying to send data from a range slider in the popup to the background, so it has to pass through chrome.extension.connect.
I found that in order to get the slider to log any data in the popup.html, I had to put some of the code in window.onload. If I want to send data to the background.js, that has to go outside of the window.onload. So then I can't pass the variable into it (something like e.target.value).

```
const inputglobal = 0;  // set a global variable to hold range input data

window.onload = function(){    
const input = document.querySelector('input#myRange');
    
input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
function updateValue(e) {
 log.textContent = e.target.value;
  console.log(e.target.value);
 inputglobal = e.target.value; // sad attempt to update the global variable    
}



}

var port = chrome.extension.connect({
      name: "Sample Communication"
 });
 port.postMessage("hello" + inputglobal); // <- this is the part where i need some sort of global variable 
 port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      console.log("message recieved" + msg); 
      
 });
```

Comment: Replace `const inputglobal` with `let inputglobal`.

Comment: thanks i tried this and it still won't update and pass out of the local function for window.onload. let me know if you want to see the code for this posted somewhere.

Comment: Well of course the function runs on an event which only happens much later after the code runs. This is how events and JavaScript in general work. Depending on what you want you may want to put the messaging code inside updateValue function.